# Anyone know how to get this font with standard Tex?

Tags: fonts

The math font looks spectacular here, and I want to use it for my thesis (LaTeX):
https://www.fernuni-hagen.de/stochastik/downloads/gruberhagen.pdf

A sample:
[image]

An ideal answer would involve a few lines that could be placed in a preamble without downloading extra stuff (I'm using Latexian).

Comment: I have several reservations about using a sans serif font for the text and serif for math.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
pdffonts Downloads/gruberhagen.pdf 
name                            type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
XOJITZ+LucidaSans-Demi          Type 1            Custom           yes yes no      74  0
ZLAUHV+LucidaSans               Type 1            Custom           yes yes no      75  0
RTWJVE+LucidaNewMath-AltItalic  Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     134  0
DPZYFZ+LucidaNewMath-Symbol     Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     135  0
OSTXAW+LucidaBright             Type 1            Custom           yes yes no     136  0
UXBXDG+LucidaNewMath-Arrows     Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     137  0
ULGBMZ+LucidaNewMath-Extension  Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     355  0
VIGTFE+LucidaSans-Italic        Type 1            Custom           yes yes no     505  0
Helvetica                       Type 1            MacRoman         no  no  no     887  0
```

Luicida Math is a commercial font and available at the TUG store: http://tug.org/store/lucida/

Answer (score 4):

Issuing `strings gruberhagen.pdf | grep FontName` yields

```
/FontName /UXBXDG+LucidaNewMath-Arrows
/FontName /ULGBMZ+LucidaNewMath-Extension
/FontName /RTWJVE+LucidaNewMath-AltItalic
/FontName /DPZYFZ+LucidaNewMath-Symbol
/FontName /OSTXAW+LucidaBright
/FontName /XOJITZ+LucidaSans-Demi
/FontName /VIGTFE+LucidaSans-Italic
/FontName /ZLAUHV+LucidaSans
```

You can use `\usepackage{lucidabr}` in your preamble. If you do not have this package, you can download it on CTAN.

[This document](https://tug.org/store/lucida/lucidaot.pdf) gives more information on Lucida OpenType.

I just read a bit more about it [here](http://tug.org/store/lucida/index.html) and it seems that Lucida is not available for free.

Answer (score 2):

When you look at the document properties in your pdf viewer, you see it uses `Lucida Sans`  (for text) and `Lucida New Math`. It's not free and is available from  [TUG](https://tug.org/store/lucida/type1.html).